# Insulated window covers that can easily be opened and closed?

Tags: insulation, windows

We have a room with old aluminum windows. I’ve included a picture of the windows.

We have an A/C in this room, but these old windows never close tight, so most of the cool air escapes through those windows.

I’m looking for a roll-up curtain or something insulated that will prevent the cool A/C air from leaking through the windows. But this *something* should be easy to open and close since I open these windows daily.

What would you suggest?

[image]

Comment: are you saying there is no glass in the windows? ... the aluminum does not have to leak for heat to come in from the outside

Comment: The windows don’t have glass. Glass wasn’t invented yet when these windows were installed.

Comment: @rbhat glass predates aluminium by about 2000 years

Comment: Also if you open them daily, while they're open the conditioned air will blow straight out.  The leakage when they're closed is minor in comparison

Answer (score 1):

In all honesty, I would look in to new windows if you can, that's not going to be something easy to set up.

Answer (score 0):

There are framed sliding glass windows which are meant to be installed on the interior wall face to add insulation when the primary windows (usually single pane glass, in your case just shutters) are not insulated enough.  I don't know if there's a specific name for these, but they are commonly used in heritage/conservation homes where replacing the single pane windows is prohibited.  They just screw into the inside face of the wall, and you would typically be able to open one half by sliding the glass horizontally.